# How to share variable between two functions in php plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need to pass variable (calltoaction) to function 2. I tried global, it won't. How to do it?

function 1:

```
function wp_email_capture_form($calltoactiondesc,$error = 0) {
    global $calltoaction;
    /*Echo to a Variable*/
    ob_start();
    echo $calltoactiondesc;
    $calltoaction= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $url = get_option('home');
    $url = addLastCharacter($url);
?> 
    <div id="wp_email_capture" class="wp-email-capture wp-email-capture-widget wp-email-capture-widget-worldwide">
        <form name="wp_email_capture" method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <?php if (isset($_GET['wp_email_capture_error'])) {
                $error = wp_email_capture_sanitize($_GET['wp_email_capture_error']);
                echo "<div class='wp-email-capture-error'>".__('Error:','WPEC'). $error ."</div>";
            } ?>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 col-md-9 form-group textbox-group">
                <input name="wp-email-capture-email" id="wp-email-capture-email-widget" type="text" class="wp-email-capture-email wp-email-capture-input wp-email-capture-widget-worldwide wp-email-capture-email-widget wp-email-capture-email-input wp-email-capture-email-input-widget form-control input-lg input" title="Email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group textbox-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="wp_capture_action" value="1" />
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php _e('SUBMIT','WPEC'); ?>" class="wp-email-capture-submit wp-email-capture-widget-worldwide subscribe-button" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  
<?php
}
```

NOTE: I pass variable only via function 1. when I submit "process" function shown below calls and executes. But the global variable not passing.

```
function wp_email_capture_process() {
  if(isset($_REQUEST['wp_capture_action'])) {
    wp_email_capture_signup();
  } 
......
}
```

function 2:

```
function wp_email_capture_signup() {
  global $wpdb;
  global $calltoaction;
  // Random confirmation code
  $confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));
  $starturl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  if (strpos($starturl, "?") === false) { 
    $extrastring = "?"; 
  } else { 
    $extrastring = "&"; 
  } 
  $email = $_REQUEST['wp-email-capture-email'];
  if (!is_email($email)) {
    $error = urlencode(__('Not a valid email','WPEC'));
    $url = $starturl . $extrastring . "wp_email_capture_error=" . $error;
    wp_redirect($url);  
    die();
  }
.... 
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $GLOBALS var

```
$i=1;

function &test1 ($i) {
    $GLOBALS['i']++;
    return $GLOBALS['i'];
}

function test2(){
    echo $GLOBALS['i'];
}

test1($i);
test2();
// echo $i : 2;
```

Hope it's help you

Answer (score 0):

In order for global variables to work, you need to declare the global variable outside of all the functions...

```
global $calltoaction;

function wp_email_capture_form($calltoactiondesc,$error = 0) {
    global $calltoaction;
    /* the rest of your function */
}

function wp_email_capture_process() {
    /* the rest of your function */
}

function wp_email_capture_signup() {
    global $wpdb,
           $calltoaction;
    /* the rest of your function */
}
```

Because you haven't set (or at least haven't shown us that you've set) the global variable outside all the functions, the functions have no idea what the variable is.

Also note that when using "global" inside a function, you only need to type "global" once and have a comma separated list of global variables after...